# Can't convert from String to Timestamp; Wrong format

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, date, querydsl

I'm getting the following error when trying to pass a date object from AngularJS to java spring backend:

> Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type 
>       [@javax.persistence.Column java.sql.Timestamp] for value 
>       '2018-06-12T22:00:00.000Z'; nested exception is 
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be
>        yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]

So far I tried to format the date object to a string in the expected format:

```
$filter('date')(date, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

which leads to an error telling:

> Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2018-06-13 12:00:00` to be a date

Seems like I need to pass a date object but I can't find a way to influence the date format AngularJS is attempting to convert to.

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please?

Comment: The string you got parses nicely into a `java.time.Instant`, even without any formatter since the format is the default ISO 8601. How you persuade Spring into doing that and saving the `Instant` into the database I don’t know (sorry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `java.time.Instant`

Your backend service is outdated, using a legacy class `java.sql.Timestamp`. That class was supplanted years ago by `java.time.Instant`.

If you make that change your backend to use `Instant`, you’ll have no problem passing a String such as `2018-06-12T22:00:00.000Z`. That string is using a standard format defined in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). That format is the ideal way to exchange date-time values as text.

The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

I know Hibernate has been updated to support the *java.time* classes. I don’t know about JPA.  (I don’t use either.)

Answer (score -1):

You can convert a date string to a date object using any format like this:

```
Date parseDateString(String dateString){
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
}
```

You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: As Ole V.V. commented, FYI, you are using troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` that are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Thank you guys for correcting me. I was unaware of this since my workplace requires me to work with Java 7